# How do I do a ResultSet in SQLite in Iphone for getting a set of values and to traverse through it?

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

I am doing a program involving a database. I have a query that will fetch all the data from the table.

But I want to traverse through each record and get each column values of each record.

For that, we usually use a ResultSet. But since I am a beginner in SQLite, I dont have any idea on how to do this? Do anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google for 'iphone sql tutorial' but first ask yourself whether you should be using [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) instead.